# a haskell function to test if an integer appears after another integer

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I'm writing a function called  after  which takes a list of integers and two integers as parameters. after list num1 num2  should  return True  if  num1  occurs   in   the   list   and  num2  occurs   in  list afternum1. (Not necessarily immediately after).

```
after::[Int]->Int->Int->Bool
after [] _ _=False
after [x:xs] b c 
    |x==b && c `elem` xs =True 
    |x/=b && b `elem` xs && b `elem` xs=True
```

This is what I have so far,my biggest problem is that I don't know how to force num2 to be after num1.

Comment: what should the function return if either of num1,num2 isn't present in the list , e.g. `after [2,3,4] 5 2` or `after [2,3,4] 2 5` or `after [2,3,4] 1 7` ?

Comment: by the way, your function isn't recursive which it should be

Comment: then it should return false

Comment: also what if either of num1,num2 is repeated in the list , e.g. `after [2,3,4,2] 2 4` should the answer be `True` because `4` is after the first `2` or should it be `False` because the last `2` is after `4` ?

Answer (score 7):

There's a few different ways to approach this one; while it's tempting to go straight for recursion on this, it's nice to
avoid using recursion explicitly if there's another option.

Here's a simple version using some list utilities. Note that it's a Haskell idiom that the object we're operating over is usually the last argument. In this case switching the arguments lets us write it as a pipeline with it's third argument (the list) passed implicitly:

```
after :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Bool
after a b = elem b . dropWhile (/= a)
```

Hopefully this is pretty easy to understand; we drop elements of the list until we hit an `a`, assuming we find one we check if there's a `b` in the remaining list. If there was no `a`, this list is `[]` and obviously there's no `b` there, so it returns False as expected.

You haven't specified what happens if 'a' and 'b' are equal, so I'll leave it up to you to adapt it for that case. HINT: add a `tail` somewhere ;)

Here are a couple of other approaches if you're interested:

This is pretty easily handled using a fold;

We have three states to model. Either we're looking for the first elem, or
we're looking for the second elem, or we've found them (in the right order).

```
data State =
  FindA | FindB | Found
  deriving Eq
```

Then we can 'fold' (aka reduce) the list down to the result of whether it matches or not.

```
after :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Bool
after a b xs = foldl go FindA xs == Found
  where
    go FindA x = if x == a then FindB else FindA
    go FindB x = if x == b then Found else FindB
    go Found _ = Found
```

You can also do it recursively if you like:

```
after :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Bool
after _ _ [] = False
after a b (x:xs) 
  | x == a = b `elem` xs
  | otherwise = after a b xs
```

Cheers!

Comment: Nice alternatives. Some of these might not be perfectly equivalent in the case `a==b`, if I see correctly. My preferred solutions are the first (compact) and the last one (easy to read). `foldl` seems a bit unappropriate for this since you don't really need to fold over the full list.

Comment: @chi Agreed; they didn't mention preferred behaviour for that case so I didn't worry about it.

Comment: `not . null . dropWhile (/= b) = elem b`

Answer (score 1):

You can split it into two parts: the first one will find the first occurrence of `num1`. After that, you just need to drop all elements before it and just check that `num2` is in the remaining part of the list.

There's a standard function [`elemIndex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.2.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v%3AelemIndex) for the first part. The second one is just `elem`.

```
import Data.List (elemIndex)

after xs x y = 
    case x `elemIndex` xs of 
        Just i -> y `elem` (drop (i + 1) xs)
        Nothing -> False
```

Comment: But you split the first part in two parts too. Combination of `elemIndex` and `drop` means you need to go over the first part of `xs` twice, which is bad if the first occurrence of `x` is somewhere close to the end. It's better done using `dropWhile`, as in Chris Penner's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to implement it without `elem` or `elemIndex`, you could include a subroutine. Something like:

```
after xs b c = go xs False
  where go (x:xs) bFound
          | x == b && not (null xs) = go xs True
          | bFound && x == c        = True
          | null xs                 = False
          | otherwise               = go xs bFound
```